# Migrating Access 97 to Sql Server - Version Error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssma

I have Sql Server Migration Assistant for Access v2.7, running on Windows Server 2016. On the same server I have 64bit version of Access 2016 and a 32bit version (I assume) of Access 97.

I am able to migrate Access 2007.accdb files on this server. However, when I click add database and choose an Access 97.mdb file I get the following error:

*"Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application."*

Is it possible to migrate (directly) from Access 97 using this tool?

The following link suggested it should be:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql

*Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access is a tool for migrating databases from Microsoft Access versions 97 through 2010 to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 / Microsoft SQL Server 2008 / Microsoft SQL Server 2012 / Microsoft SQL Server 2014 / Microsoft SQL Server 2016 / Microsoft SQL Server 2017*

Comment: Is your Access DB workgroup protected?

Comment: No, there’s not security on the access db.

Comment: I don't know if it should work or not, but have you tried upgrading the MDB to a later version of Access first?

Comment: Yes it does work if I open the mdb with Access 2007 and SaveAs accdb. I’m trying to avoid having to do that thought because I have lots of databases to migrate to Sql Server.